# Convert double to int (java)

Tags: java, int, double, type-conversion

I'm trying to make a program to simulate the solar system.

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    double X=(160*Math.cos((2*PI*i)/365));
    double Y=(160*Math.sin((2*PI*i)/365));
    posX=Math.round(X);
    posY=Math.round(Y);
    cadre.repaint();
    sleep(200);
}
f.setVisible(false);
```

To make my planets turning around the sun, I have a formula; the problem is that i have a double number with this formula, and i can't make him become an int (i tried floor(X), Math.round(X), doesn't work (error : incompatible types : possible lossy conversion from long to int)

[[image]]

You'll see that it is not really java but he works as Java (it's some Javascool), so your advices will probably work for me!

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question instead of an image

Comment: for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
  double X=(160*Math.cos((2*PI*i)/365));
  double Y=(160*Math.sin((2*PI*i)/365));
  posX=Math.round(X);
  posY=Math.round(Y);
  cadre.repaint();
  sleep(200);
 }
 f.setVisible(false);

Comment: That's here but i don't know how the other do to have some "clean" code lines in this website :/

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34577277/edit) link to  update your question. The comments are not for code. You can use the `{ } ` button to format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add cast to int like:

```
posX = (int) Math.round(X);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @M.Rio Since you are new here. So just to let you know you can appreciate peoples help by up-voting and accepting their answers.

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a `double` to an `int` the compiler can't determine whether this is a safe operation or not.  You have to use an explicit cast such as

```
double d = ...
int i = (int) d; // implicitly does a floor(d);
```

In Java 8 there is function to help detect whether the cast was safe (from a long at least)  [Math.toIntExact](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

```
int i = Math.toIntExact((long) d); // implicitly does a floor(d);
```

You can do this running the GUI Event Loop as a periodic task.

```
 double X= 160*Math.cos(i * 2 * PI / 360); 
 double Y= 160*Math.sin(i * 2 * PI / 360); 
 posX = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(X));
 posY = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(Y));
 cadre.repaint();
 // note you have to return so the image can actually be drawn.
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)