# How to round double to integer (without show auditor and zero number)?

Tags: java, android

How I can round the numbers of double variable when are was equal your integer values?

Indeed I want to change numbers example `4.0` or `8.0` to `4` or `8` without show the auditor and zero number. How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert double to int (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577277/convert-double-to-int-java)

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it:

```
double doubleNum = 4.0;
int num = (int) doubleNum;  // 4
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But I want to enter doubleNum by EditText. How about this?

Comment: What does that mean? Please elaborate more on your problem. Your original question doesn't even mention an EditText. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a variable bla, when you want to use bla  just do (int)bla